# Удалённое подключение к raspberry

Tags: raspberry-pi, rdp

При удалённом подключении к raspberry по RDP под одним логином pi, почему то создается новая сессия,  почему? хотя под этим логином уже локально зашли

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому, что каждая **сессия** в Linux - это **сессия**. Со своим шеллом, окружением, памятью и т.д. Без всякого RDP - залогиньтесь локально, а потом подключитесть по ssh или telnet или через COM-порт под тем же самым логином и вы увидите, **двух** пользователей с одним логином. Можно запретить такое поведение системы. Тогда в любой момент только один пользователь с данным логином может быть в системе.

Объяснение довольно простое. В давние-давние времена юности Unix, когда персоналок ещё не было, а были майн-фреймы с кучей подключённых терминалов, каждый пользователь системы мог сесть за любой терминал и начать работать там. А админы системы могли бегать по всему зданию и логиниться одновременно в разных местах - это действительно было нужно. Но рядовым пользователям, как правило, одновременный логин запрещался. Но это - опционально.

Comment: А как можно заблокировать? можете подсказать?

Comment: @GetTM  Ответа я не знаю - с тех пор много воды утекло. Но, если он и есть, то искать его надо среди документации по NSS/PAM. Может быть, вам стоит попробовать двухфакторную аутентификацию, если уж это так важно?